# Extremely slow rendering time using Moviepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, moviepy

I'm trying to create the following: two stacked videos (one on top of each other) with subtitles (like those videos you see in tiktok) from an srt file. For this, I'm first taking the top and bottom video and creating a CompositeVideoClip:\

```
clips_array([[video_clip], [random_bottom_clip]])
```

Then, I'm taking this CompositeVideoClip and using a generator, creating the SubtitlesClip which then I will add to another CompositeVideoClip:

```
sub = SubtitlesClip(os.path.join(temp_directory, f"subtitles.srt"), generator)
final = CompositeVideoClip([myvideo, sub.set_position(('center', 'center'))]).set_duration("00:02:40")
```

Lastly, I'm adding some more text-clips (just an small title for the video) and rendering:

```
video_with_text = CompositeVideoClip([final] + text_clips)
video_with_text.write_videofile(part_path, fps=30,threads=12,codec="h264_nvenc")
```

Here is the problem. I tried to render a video of 180 seconds (3 minutes) and the video takes up to hour and a half (80 minutes) which is wild. I tried some render settings as you can see like changing 'codec' and using all the 'threads' of my CPU.
I tried to not use so many CompositeVideoClips, I read that when you concatenate those the final render will suffer a lot, but I didn't manage to find a way "not to use" that many CompositeVideoClips, any idea?

My PC is not that bad. 16GB, AMD Ryzen 5 5600 6-Core , NVIDIA 1650 SUPER.

My goal is to at least bring the render to less than an hour. Right now is like **1.23s/it**

Comment: first you could check which part makes problem. Maybe you should first run only first part and check time, next run first and second part and check time, etc.

Comment: What is the video resolution and framerate of the resulting video? Are you sure your system supports nvenc, or maybe it uses a fallback encoder if there is no nvenc?

Comment: @maddes8cht final video resolution is 1706x1920 and fps are 30. My system supports nvenc because I have NVIDIA and also because if I run "ffmpeg -encoders”  I have it there. Anyway, I already tried so many encoders, which one's you suggest?

Comment: @furas I tried running each part, top and bottom video render speed its: 14.48it/s, second part with the subtitles gets slower: t:   5.12it/s. For context, It is a video of 13 minutes. The thing is that, the last part, where I add some text-clips, I cut the video in 3 minutes parts, each part with all the edits takes around hour and half.

Comment: If your hardware supports nvenc, then nvenc should be your fastest option. I would have expected that a machine like yours should be much faster in encoding a 3 minutes hig rsolution clip with nvenc.
Somehow i have the qustion: Whot is your bottleneck? 
Maybe it`s not the encoder. 
How large (filesize) are your input files, how large the output?

Comment: And what is your OS?

Comment: @maddes8cht Windows 10

Comment: In task manager in tab "Performance" you could probably see something about what actaully your bottleneck is (while encoding) .
Maybeeven send another screenshot inside the question

Comment: @maddes8cht I think the main problem is the concatenation of CompositeVideoClips. As I said to furas, as I render each part, which is a CompositeVideoClip essentially, takes longer and longer. The issue is that I don't know how to replace the CompositeVideoClips and get the same result. The idea would be to just use one final CompositeVideoClip to mount the whole video so I only have to render one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the subtitles.
Currently, TextClips in moviepy are abhorrently slow, they render every frame even if no changes have been made to them.

SubtitlesClip is just a wrapper for TextClip.

I'm working on a fix for this, if you want to try your hand at it, edit this script: `moviepy/video/tools/subtitles.py`

EDIT:
After some digging, subtitles often bottleneck due to the blit_on function because of how it's used in CompositeVideoClip. You can also check `moviepy/video/tools/drawing.py` as is what blit_on calls to draw frames.

I've found a hacky way to get around this which is by making the subtitles box smaller. If you have a transparent background for your subtitles the transparent part still gets rendered and a bunch of calculations occur in drawing.py (!!). To fix this, make your SubtitlesClip's size as small as possible without affecting the rendering of the text.

This is not a real fix, but I didn't have much success multithreading/optimizing the code and offloading to GPU can be really messy, I just don't think video rendering lends itself very cleanly to python. (It's very resource-intensive)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).